# Same Binary Tree Exercise Given two binary trees, return true if they are identical

Tags: java

I wrote the following code but I only get partial credit and I'm not 100% sure of how to fix it.

```
public  boolean MBTsame(BinNode root1, BinNode root2)
{
    if (root1 == root2 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(root1 != null && root2 != null){
        return true;
    }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: You return `true` if both roots are not null (and not equal to each other).

Comment: Maybe you are 90% sure what could be the problem. Some nice debugging techniques would be to construct test cases. Do they result in expected output?

Comment: You need to check the children nodes. You're only comparing the root node. Hint: recursion